# BeautifulSoup4 doesn't read &approx; as an HTML entity

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-entities

This seems familiar; why does `&approx;` not get picked up by html.parser?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> for html in ['hey &lsquo; 3','hey &pi;','hey &approx; 3']:
...     print repr(unicode(BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')))
... 
u'hey \u2018 3'
u'hey \u03c0'
u'hey &amp;approx 3'
```

Comment: Maybe because you're using a dead version of python and not passing a parser to BeautifulSoup instance?

Comment: `html.parser` does the same thing; I'll update my question.

Comment: And yes, I know it's a "dead" version of Python, but I have constraints in this particular case that limit my use to Python 2.7. This is a valid question; to whoever downvoted, could you please reconsider?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out myself from looking at the [bs4 source code for the htmlparser builder](https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py#L81).

BeautifulSoup's builder uses the entity-name-to-character mapping in  `bs4.dammit.EntitySubstitution.HTML_ENTITY_TO_CHARACTER` so it is easy to patch.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rawhtml = '<p>&lsquo; &approx; &pi; &theta; 3.</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(rawhtml, 'html.parser')
print('Before: %s' % repr(soup))

# &approx; -> \u2248
# from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references    
bs4.dammit.EntitySubstitution.HTML_ENTITY_TO_CHARACTER['approx'] = u'\u2248'

soup = BeautifulSoup(rawhtml, 'html.parser')
print('After: %s' % repr(soup))
```

which prints out

```
Before: <p>\u2018 &amp;approx \u03c0 \u03b8 3.</p>
After: <p>\u2018 \u2248 \u03c0 \u03b8 3.</p>
```

Comment: You know, it's really incredibly frustrating to be treated with a hostile attitude here. I had a legitimate question with a fairly straightforward and useful answer. This site used to be friendly and helpful.